# parse-server set ACL for user and role in afterSave

Tags: acl, roles, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I'm trying to set up a "general_user" role for my app so admin can ban a user by removing them from that role.

This code:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
var user = request.object;
if (user.existed()) { return; }

var roleQuery = new Parse.Query(CONSTANTS.ROLE_CLASSNAME);
roleQuery.equalTo("name", CONSTANTS.GENERAL_USER_ROLENAME);
roleQuery.first(CONSTANTS.USE_MASTER_KEY)
    .then(function(generalUserRole) {
        if(generalUserRole)
        {
            generalUserRole.getUsers().add(user);
            return generalUserRole.save();
        }
        else
        {
            var role = new Parse.Role(CONSTANTS.GENERAL_USER_ROLENAME, new Parse.ACL());
            role.getUsers().add(user);
            return role.save();
        }
    }).then(function(generalUserRole) {
        var acl = new Parse.ACL();
        acl.setWriteAccess(user, true);
        acl.setRoleReadAccess(generalUserRole, true);
        req.object.setACL(acl);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
});
```

Results in an ACL that's `public read, user(write)` (Reading in the dashboard).

I've tried saving the saving the req.object after adding the ACL.

I've tried with and without `res.success()` (which I understand is not necessary in afterSaves).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tested your code and found some issues and fix them. The issues that i found were:

1. The response is not required in **afterSave** only the request so you don't need to write response.success()
2. You did good when you set the ACL for the user but you didn't save it.. if you will not run **save** at the end it will not save the your changes so  you need to run **save** with **useMasterKey : true** in order to save the changes

At the end your code should look like the following:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function (req) {

    var user = req.object;
    if (user.existed()) { return; }

    var roleQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
    roleQuery.equalTo("name", "someRole");

    roleQuery.first({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function (role) {

        if (role) {
            role.getUsers().add(user);
            return role.save();
        } else {
            var myNewRole = new Parse.Role("someRole", new Parse.ACL());
            myNewRole.getUsers().add(user);
            return myNewRole.save()
        }

    }).then(function (userRole) {
        var acl = new Parse.ACL();
        acl.setWriteAccess(user, true);
        acl.setRoleReadAccess(userRole, true);
        user.setACL(acl);
        return user.save(null,{ useMasterKey: true });
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });

});
```

Comment: So I had tried it like this and it didn't work, when you said it worked I realized it must be something else.  So I deleted all the users in my Parse.User table (with the old ACL's) and then everything worked fine.  Thank you.